# Is it possible to hide certain questions according to respondent's answer?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

For example, if I have the following format:

Question 1: (multiple choices)
A
B

Question 2:
A1
A2

Question 3:
B1
B2

If a respondent chooses A for the first question, then is it possible to hide Question 3 completely to avoid confusion? I understand that I can simply create a new page for different questions but I wish to put everything in one page for simpleness. Is there a script that will help me achieve what I want?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

That is **not** possible. Apps Script can only perform actions that you could perform manually yourself (but would be cumbersome to do). This is a Google Forms limitation.

You could write the whole "form" in Apps Script though, then you'd be able to do anything with the interface. I think there's a couple of published scripts out there that does this already.