# Is there a way to edit a Google Form using apps script while it is being filled out?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

When a user is filling out a Google Form, I would like to edit the form items based on the responses being given.

For example, when the user selects "DC" from the drop-down list in question #1, then question #2 would automatically limit it's drop-down results to "Superman", "Batman", and "Wonder Woman".

But if the user selects "Marvel" from the drop-down list in question #1, then question #2 would automatically limit it's drop-down results to "Iron Man", "Hulk", and "Thor".

I thought I could do with with apps script, but there does not seem to be an "On Edit" trigger available for Good Forms. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_4

Is there another way to have a Google Form dynamically change as it is being filled out?

Thanks!

Comment: Didn't you do any research before asking this question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @tehhowch, yeah I actually did for awhile, but I was looking to edit items, not show/hide items, so this post didn't come up.  Thanks for the post.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645999/dynamically-edit-multiple-choice-options-in-live-google-form-using-apps-script, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43273474/how-do-i-manipulate-with-google-forms-on-form-view-client-side, and others